# Where does Apache NiFi store queued (cached?) files?

Tags: macos, apache-nifi, macos-ventura

I have an instance of Apache NiFi running locally on macOS in the following directory: `/Applications/nifi-1.21.0/`.

Where should I be looking for queued FlowFiles to review and delete?

I have set up a simple pipeline that looks as follows: `GenerateFlowFile -> Queue -> PutFile`.

The `GenerateFlowFile` processor does a very simple job of creating a new `NiFi_file.txt` file with `This is a file from NiFi` as its custom text, that is then queued before being put to a file.

At this point, I have 9 queued generated text files (216 bytes in total), that I'd like to find on disk, review, and delete if necessary.

Listing the queue, I can look up all 9 files, their UUIDs and filesizes. I can even find in the FlowFile the path, that is set to `./`. However, I am unable to find these files anywhere in the `nifi-1.21.0` directory.

Comment: Check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#repositories and https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#write-ahead-flowfile-repository

Answer (score 0):

@razorrmon If you want to inspect queued files without using the NiFI UI, you can use command line API.   I would not recommend trying to inspect the filesystem in the manner you have described.   You can find a few commands here to expose the flowfile queues, and inclusive flowfiles' content:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html